# Find button with Selenium on python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to retrieve data from this button but it raises the following error: *selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable*.

Button source code:

```
<button class="Blockreact__Block-sc-1xf18x6-0 Buttonreact__StyledButton-sc-glfma3-0 bqHBns jFqMrE ActionButtonreact__StyledButton-sc-7jpoey-0" type="button"><div class="Blockreact__Block-sc-1xf18x6-0 Flexreact__Flex-sc-1twd32i-0 olSpy jYqxGr"><i value="add" size="24" class="Iconreact__Icon-sc-1gugx8q-0 irnoQt material-icons">add</i></div></button>
```

My code:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='button']")
```

Page: Add item on https://opensea.io/asset/create
[image]

[image]

Comment: Is your browser launched in full screen ?

Comment: No, I didn't try in full screen. Should I?

Comment: Yes, try that it may resolve your issue

Comment: Even though other functions of selenium work?

Comment: try using `full xpath`; and tell me the result

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: Can we have URL? would be nice if we can replicate the same in our computer.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to edit the post

Answer (score 1):

Click the button not the icon. xpath:

```
.//body/div[1]/div[1]/main/div/div/section/div[2]/form/section[6]/div[1]/div/div[2]/button
```

You can also use element waits package to ensure the button is interactable first

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(by));
```

Then click

Answer (score 0):

Since the browser maximize isn't working for you.

Did you try with ActionsChains ?

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(browser.find_element_by_xpath("//i[@value='add']/../..")).click().perform()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but It still raised selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@type='button' and text()='add']"}

Comment: okay earlier we had `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException:` error, looks like we have overcome that, but now with `NoSuchElementException:Message` for `//button[@type='button' and text()='add']` I would need to see your HTML. Can you share the relevant HTML, I see you have shared but can you share bit more outer HTML ?

Comment: okay can you try with this xpath instead `//i[@value='add']/../..` , see the update above as well.

Comment: Sorry for answering so late, by the way, I get this error: selenium.common.exceptions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: (1312, 1177) is out of bounds of viewport width (1920) and height (1080)

Comment: I tried scrolling down, but:`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <i class="Iconreact__Icon-sc-1gugx8q-0 irnoQt material-icons"> is not reachable by keyboard` raised.

Comment: I have alomost forgotten about this issue, Can I have the URL ?

Comment: Also, I tried with `browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/main/div/div/section/div/form/section[6]/div[1]/div/div[2]/button")` but it raises the following error: `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <button class="Blockreact__Block-sc-1xf18x6-0 Buttonreact__StyledButton-sc-glfma3-0 bqHBns jFqMrE ActionButtonreact__StyledButton-sc-7jpoey-0" type="button"> is not clickable at point (1312,4) because another element <a class="Linkreact__StyledA-sc-18se2b0-0 iWVmEt NavItem--main " href="/assets"> obscures it`

Comment: How do I reach to that page ? Can you help me with the steps ?

Comment: Sure: you have to install the metamask extension, after creating a wallet, sign to opensea with your metamask wallet and add  / create an item